# Filtering data in custom connector for DataStudio

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a custom `datastudio` connector that connect to WooCommerce rest API. I want to differentiate between orders placed by a `registered user` and orders placed by a `guest user`.

The WooCommerce API gives me the `customer_id` field, if the `customer_id = 0`, the order was placed by a `guest`, otherwise the `user is registered`.

I followed the google data studio tutorial :  https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started

And this is my `responseToRow` function:

```
/**
Parse the response data given the required fields of the config
@return the parsed data
*/
function responseToRows(requestedFields, response) {
  // Transform parsed data and filter for requested fields
  return response.map(function(dailyDownload) {
    var row = [];
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'id_order':
          return row.push(dailyDownload.id);
        case 'total':
          return row.push(dailyDownload.total);
        case 'date_created':
          return row.push(dailyDownload.date_created);
        case 'registered_user' :
          if(parseInt(dailyDownload.customer_id) > 0)
            return row.push(dailyDownload.customer_id);
        case 'guest_user' :
          if(parseInt(dailyDownload.customer_id) == 0)
            return row.push(dailyDownload.customer_id);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}
```

The function is similar to the one given in the tutorial, the others fields works fine. I'm just returning when the customer_id is different of 0. It seem to work, but I get null values when the condition doesn't hold.

[image: Screenshot from my data studio report]

I would like to remove the null values, having only the orders when the `customer_id` was 0 on the right and the same for the complement on the left part.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like that after filling the row array:

```
row.forEach((element, index) => {
   if(element.guest_user == null){
      // To remove the row-entry with guest_user==null
      row[index].slice(); 
   }
})
```

And if you don't want to remove the entries from the array just create a new array and use newArray.push(element); to copy the null ones into it.